# PHP Form that enters information into SQL database into one column with seperators

Tags: php, sql

I have a table with one column I want to populate, The PHP form has 4 fields

1. Field 1
2. Field 2
3. Field 3
4. Field 4

On submit of the form I want to enter the data from the 4 fields into on column into my database sepperated with a ^

So Basically the input data must look like this

Field1^Field2^Field3^Field4

Normally I insert into a Field

```
  $sql = "insert into etrack_clients set     
        Field1 = '".$Field1."',
        Field2= '".$Field2."'" ;

  if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
            $insertSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            echo $sql;
            print_r($_POST);
            echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
            echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
        }
```

How would I insert with the ^ and no spacing, On the above code this inserts into it's own Column's now into the same column

Comment: Do appologise that was type error on my side

Comment: if you EVER need to deal with those invididual fields as invididuals, e.g. you have to do a select with a `where field1=foo`, then you should NOT be stuffing multiple values into a single field. that's almost always a sign of bad design and just leads to pain and suffering later on.

Comment: to expound on what @MarcB said about poor design... why are you dealing with raw SQL queries and a **deprecated** mysql API (you arent even escaping the **user** input!)?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you need to place the four fields value into one column separated by a `^`. Here's a query that does this, try it:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO etrack_clients SET field = '{$_POST['field1']}^{$_POST['field2']}^{$_POST['field3']}^{$_POST['field4']}'";
```

Please note that this above query is not safe and can cause serious problem if not escaped. In order to escape it, web developers used to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` in order to escape special characters. This method will be deprecated starting from PHP 5.5.0. Alternatively, you can use PDO prepared statements to run queries safely.

[**PDO prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: you'd better talk about sql injection attacks, because OP's going to use this literally and then wonder why their site got trashed.